# Vector insert() causes program to crash

Tags: c++, vector, insert, crash

This is the first part of a function I have that's causing my program to crash:

```
vector<Student> sortGPA(vector<Student> student) {
    vector<Student> sorted;
    Student test = student[0];
    cout << "here\n";
    sorted.insert(student.begin(), student[0]);
    cout << "it failed.\n";
         ...
```

It crashes right at the `sorted` part because I can see "here" on the screen but not "it failed." The following error message comes up:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

(a long path here...)

Expression: vector emplace iterator outside range

For more information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
```

I'm not sure what's causing the problem now, since I have a similar line of code elsewhere `student.insert(student.begin() + position(temp, student), temp);` that does not crash (where `position` returns an int and `temp` is another declaration of a struct Student). What can I do to resolve the problem, and how is the first insert different from the second one?

Comment: You really ought to pass your vector into the function by reference, too...

Comment: @Mike DeSimone--but I don't want the vector to be changed though, I just want to get a changed vector

Comment: @wrongusername: Then use a `const` reference.  What you're doing now is (when the function is called) creating a copy of the vector, which is then passed in.  Or is there something in the function where you need to locally alter the student vector?

Comment: @Mike DeSimone--yes, I need a changed copy of the vector. If I needed to change the original, though, would be the difference between a void function changing the vector versus setting the function equal to a function returning a changed copy of the vector?

Comment: @wrongusername: I think you misunderstand me.  I take it you don't want the function to change the vector passed in for `student`.  But I see your code creating another vector named `sorted`, and am assuming you make changes to it rather than `student`, ending the function with `return sorted;`.  In this case, where `student` is read but not altered, you can specify `student` as a const reference, removing the need for the compiler to duplicate the vector passed in as `student`.

Comment: As for `void sortGPA(..., vector<Student>& result)` vs. `vector<Student> sortGPA(...)`, the latter, *at best*, will equal the performance of the former, and if your compiler's optimizer isn't up to it, there could be up to two hidden vector copies in the latter.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone--thank you! yes, apparently I did misunderstand you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be:

```
sorted.insert(sorted.begin(), student[0]);
```

You were passing the iterator from the wrong instance.

Answer (score 3):

When you use `std::vector::insert ( iterator position, const T& x );`, the iterator `position` must point into that same vector.  You're using an iterator from `student` with `sorted.insert`, which dies.